# Bash script to rename files and Zip folder

Tags: bash, macos-high-sierra

I wrote a script to rename some files in a folder and then zip the entire folder.  The renaming works but the zip always fails with a "permission denied". This is my script:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo 'Renaming .env file to .env.local...'
mv ~/Workspace/apps/v4/.env  ~/Workspace/apps/v4/.env.local
echo 'Renaming .env.production file to .env...'
mv ~/Workspace/apps/v4/.env.production  ~/Workspace/apps/v4/.env
echo 'Zipping folder for production…'
zip ../exampleapp.zip ~/Workspace/apps/v4 -x ".idea/*" ".editorconfig" ".gitattributes" ".gitignore" "example.pem" "public/node_modules/*" "public/untitled_folder/*" "public/bower_components/*" "public/src/*"
echo 'Renaming .env.local to .env...'
mv ~/Workspace/apps/v4/.env.local  ~/Workspace/apps/v4/.env
```

I do not know any way around this and would like to know how I can be able to run this script without "permission denied" error.

Comment: In what directory are you when you run this? Your home directory? Do you have permission to write into the directory above (that is, permission to create `../exampleapp.zip`)? Try changing to just `exampleapp.zip` and see.

Comment: I'm inside the v4 directory, that's where the script is located.